# How do you encrypt a column in Snow SQL if the column name has spaces?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to encrypt a column with sensitive information in Snowflake. The usual syntax to encrypt a column is `ENCRYPT( <value_to_encrypt> , <passphrase>)`
The tricky part is that the column name has spaces. If I enclose it in single quotes, Snowflake is encrypting the column name itself and if I enclose in double quotes, it is resulting in a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, the value to be encrypted has to be provided exactly as defined during CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(id INT, "col with space" TEXT);
INSERT INTO tab(id, "col with space") VALUES (1, 'abc');

SELECT id, "col with space", ENCRYPT("col with space", 'my_pass_phrase')
FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]